# Select - where multiples valores con Datatables y PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, datatables

Estoy haciendo un sistema en el cual me muestra las materias que están vacantes, envío 2 parámetros que es la clave de la escuela y el ciclo escolar, lo intente con JavaScript ajax y me sale correcto, sin embargo, queriendo mejorar con DataTables me encuentro con un problema, pues, ya no me arroja ningun dato, ni si quiera me arroja el "alert" característico cuando no es un formato json, lo tengo hecho de la siguiente manera:

en mi archivo JS lo llamo con una función:

```
function buscarMaterias() {

if($.fn.dataTable.isDataTable('#Tabla_materias')){
    tabla_materias.clear().draw();
    tabla_materias.destroy();
}

let ciclo = $('#ciclo_esc').val();
let depe = $('#depe').val();

tabla_materias = $('#Tabla_materias').DataTable({
    bDeferRender:true,
    ajax: {
        url: '../administrador/config/materias_vacantes.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataSrc: "",
        data: {
            ciclo: ciclo,
            depe: depe
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    }       
})
};
```

Por otro lado mi documento PHP donde recibo los datos de búsqueda está hecho de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php 
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: access");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

require './bd.php';

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=='POST'){
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$depe = $_POST['depe'];
$ciclo = $_POST['ciclo'];

$consulta = "SELECT id, asignatura, semestre, grupo, plan_est, total FROM asignaturas WHERE asig_depe='$depe' AND asig_ciclo='$ciclo' EXCEPT SELECT id_asig, asignatura, semestre, grupo, plan_est ,total FROM vw_doc_mate ORDER BY semestre ASC";
$query = pg_query($conn, $consulta );

$tabla=array('data'=>array());    

while($row = pg_fetch_all($query, PGSQL_ASSOC)){

    $tabla['data'][] = array(
        $row['id'],
        $row['asignatura'],
        $row['plan_est'],
        $row['semestre'],
        $row['grupo'],
        $row['total']
    );
}

echo json_encode($tabla,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
}
```

Pero la #Tabla_materias queda con un constante "loading..." y de ahí no pasa, ¿cómo lo puedo solucionar?... agradecería mucho su ayuda

Comment: viste que sale en la consola???

Comment: La consola no me arroja ningún error, sabes como puedo depurar?... colocar el succes:function() o el error:function()  ??

Comment: ya vi que si me arroja el mensaje de json invalid, despues de un tiempo